# Problem with inverse FFT for 2D array by manual

Tags: python, transform, fft

I have a problem to do inverse FFT2 by integration.

I prepare 4 densities each in another time ( gausse  function for each time I move a gauss by 1 ).

Then I have 2D array filled with densities, doing fft2, prepare omega and k domain and then I want to integrate over all k and omega to retrieve original density in t =0.

But my density is shifted to the right from central point, and when I add the time to retrieve all densities, densities change height.

Can any one check my code and explain what I doing wrong?

```
from os import path
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from operator import add
from operator import sub
import gc
from pathlib import Path
from pylab import *
import cmath

x = []
indataxx = []

mmn = int(10)
dd = Path("""/home/maciek/test""")
outpath = str(dd/'test')


filename = dd/'nb.dat'
#filename = '/media/maciej/Nowy/trap_per_mu_0.6_Nb_300/gbf_' + str(i) + '/energy.dat'
indata = np.genfromtxt(filename ,usecols=(0))

mx = 300
nx = int(mx/2)
dx = 0.1

dl = len(indata)/(int(mx))
dl = int(dl)
print("ilosc zrzutow ", dl)


for i in range(0,mx):
    x.append(dx * (i-nx))

l2=[]

for j in range(0,dl):
    col = []
    for i in range (0,mx):
        col.append(indata[j*mx + i])
    l2.append(col)


l2 = np.array(l2)


# Apply 2D FFT
l2_shift = np.fft.ifftshift(l2)
l2_shift_fft = np.fft.fft2(l2_shift)
l2_shift_fft = np.fft.fftshift(l2_shift_fft)

magnitude_spectrum = np.abs(l2_shift)**2
print("Shape of magnitude_spectrum:", magnitude_spectrum.shape)


dt = mmn
Freqomega = np.linspace(-np.pi/(dt),np.pi/(dt),l2_shift_fft.shape[0],endpoint = False)
Freq_k_wec = np.linspace(-np.pi/(dx),np.pi/(dx),l2_shift_fft.shape[1],endpoint = False)

print("Shape of Freqomega:", Freqomega.shape)       #omegi
print("Shape of Freq_k_wec:", Freq_k_wec.shape)    #wektor k


S,D = np.meshgrid(Freq_k_wec, Freqomega)


with open(dd/'test_freqx.txt', "w") as f:
    np.savetxt(f, Freq_k_wec)

with open(dd/'test_freqy.txt', "w") as f:
    np.savetxt(f, Freqomega)

filename1 = dd/'test_freqy.txt'
indata1 = np.loadtxt(filename1, usecols=(0))

filename11 = dd/'test_freqx.txt'
indata11 = np.loadtxt(filename11, usecols=(0))


evo = []
evo1 = []
time = 4


print(" dk step ", Freq_k_wec[1]-Freq_k_wec[0])
print(" dw step ", Freqomega[1]-Freqomega[0])

ss = mx*dx/2
print(" przesuniecie po fft ", ss)


for yy in range(time):
    print("time " , yy)
    for u in range(len(indata1)):
        print("omega ", indata1[u])

        for j in range(mx):

            tmp = 0.

            for i in range(l2_shift_fft .shape[1]):
                tmp = tmp + l2_shift_fft[u , i] * np.exp( 1j * indata11[i] * x[j] )             #integral over k

            tmp = tmp * np.exp( 1j * indata1[u] * yy)
            tmp = tmp * np.abs(Freq_k_wec[1]-Freq_k_wec[0]) * np.abs(Freqomega[1]-Freqomega[0])  #dk*dw
            #tmp = tmp * np.exp( 1j * np.pi/dx ) * np.exp( 1j * np.pi/dt ) #shift
            evo.append(tmp)




for u in range(0,time,1):
    for i in range(mx):
        with open(dd/'xx_den.txt', "ab") as f:
            np.savetxt(f, np.c_[x[i],evo[u*mx + i].real/(l2_shift_fft.shape[0] * l2_shift_fft.shape[1])])

for yy in range(time):
    print(yy)
    for j in range(mx):
        atmp = 0.
        for u in range(len(indata1)):
            atmp = atmp + evo[yy*mx + u*(mx) + j]
        evo1.append(atmp.real/(l2_shift_fft.shape[0] * l2_shift_fft.shape[1]))



for u in range(time):
    for i in range(0,mx):
        with open(dd/'yy_test.txt', "ab") as f:
            np.savetxt(f, np.c_[x[i],evo1[u*mx + i]])
```

I tried all possible with many shifts but the shifts change one side of gausse ( only right side is deform )

Comment: I coped old code where was one error, these is correct term:
atmp = atmp + evo[yy * mx * len(indata1) + u * (mx) + j]

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: In these code I tried to do Inverse Fourier transform by explicitly integration